# Order of primary key and foreign key referencing matters

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am creating a database containing video rental information. In the copy table i have the film number (FNr) and the copy number (cpyNr) as primary key (there is more, but to simplify the problem i have removed them). In the second table, rent, the film number (FNr),copy number (cpyNr) and the customer number (CNr) is part of the key. The copy number is referenced from the copy table. Film number and customer number will be referenced from elsewhere, but is not relevant for the question and i have removed them for simplicity.

The problem is, when i run the code below as it is now, it doesn't work. I get a foreign key constrain fails.

```
drop database if exists video;
create database video;
use video;

CREATE TABLE copy
(
FNr INT,
cpyNr INT,
CONSTRAINT copyPK
PRIMARY KEY (FNr,cpyNr)
);

CREATE TABLE rent
(
FNr INT,
cpyNr INT,
CNr INT,
CONSTRAINT rentPK
PRIMARY KEY (FNr,cpyNr,CNr),
CONSTRAINT copyPK FOREIGN KEY (cpyNr) 
REFERENCES copy(cpyNr)
);
```

What does work however is if i change the order of the columns in the primary key of copy to

```
PRIMARY KEY (cpyNr,FNr)
```

it does work, but i cannot understand why.

Comment: First thing Primary column can be only one column in a table but in your case it may be composite primary key so cross check once again

Comment: A foreign key requires an index in the destination table that starts with the foreign key column(s) (so `cpynr, xxx` works, `xxx, cpynr` not). Just add an additional index `copy(cpynr)`, and the choice of your primary key does not matter anymore.

Comment: Your foreign key constraint should look more like this: `CONSTRAINT copyPK FOREIGN KEY (FNr, cpyNr) REFERENCES copy (FNr, cpyNr)`.